# Find the nearest previous date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a list of dates and a target date object. I need to find the nearest previous date(before the target date). I have tried the following but I don't think it will work for only previous date.

```
private Date getDateNearest(List<Date> dates, Date targetDate) {
    Date returnDate = targetDate;

    for (Date date : dates) {
        if (date.compareTo(targetDate) <= 0 && date.compareTo(returnDate) > 0) {
            returnDate=date;
        }
    }

    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: Think this might be a duplicate of the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186311/best-way-to-find-date-nearest-to-target-in-a-list-of-dates?rq=1

Comment: I just checked the code. I think its fine.

Comment: This logic is potentially wrong if the list of dates passed in is not sorted. (nevermind.. see comments below)

Comment: @jervine10 Why do you think so?

Comment: Note that `Date` has `.before()` and `.after()` methods, which behave the same as comparing

Comment: @peter.petrov Sorry I just looked at it again, I misread the logic. It does potentially look correct. I'd have to write a Unit test to verify. That's probably what the questioner should do as well =)

Answer (score 1):

### Standard library one-liner

Since `Date` implements `Comparable`, this should be as easy as

```
Date previousDate = new TreeSet<Date>(dates).lower(targetDate);
```

Obviously this brings in a bit of extra overhead for the convenience of a one-liner, though.

From the [Javadoc for `lower()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#lower%28E%29):

> Returns the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or null if there is no such element.

**Edit:**  Looking at your code, it seems like you also want to return `targetDate` itself if it's in the set, so you can use `floor(targetDate)` instead.

### Guava approach

Here's a more performant one-liner using Guava:

```
Date earlierDate = Ordering.natural().max(
     Iterables.filter(dates, Range.lessThan(targetDate)));
```

Unlike the pure Java approach, this does not require an extra data structure to be populated, and only requires one pass of the list.  It creates a lazily-populated `Iterable` containing only dates less than `targetDate`, and then gets the max of that iterable.

Again, if you want it to accept `targetDate` as well, use `Range.atMost` instead of `Range.lessThan`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Date getDateNearest(List<Date> dates, Date targetDate) {
    Date returnDate = null; // Nearest before.
    for (Date date : dates) {
        if (date.before(targetDate) || date.equals(targetDate) {
            if (returnDate == null || returnDate.before(date)) {
                returnDate = date;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

Your error: initialising returnDate on targetDate gives an unbeatable nearest optimum.
Mind, maybe:

```
    return returnDate == null ? targetDate : returnDate;
```

*BTW April 1st? (Editing the question.) LOL*

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
private Date getDateNearest(List<Date> dates, Date targetDate) {
    Date returnDate = targetDate;
    long targetMillis = targetDate.getTime();
    long mindiff = Long.MAX_VALUE;        
    for (Date date : dates) {
        long dateMillis = date.getTime();
        long diff = Math.abs(dateMillis-targetMillis);
        if( diff < mindiff){
            mindiff = diff;
            returnDate = date;
        }
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```