# Compare date and Time without changing their format and find nearest value among them

Tags: java, android, android-date

I have list of dates:

```
23/08/2014 8:23:23
24/08/2014 5:23:23
24/08/2014 6:23:23
24/08/2014 7:23:23
24/08/2014 7:25:23
24/08/2014 8:23:23
```

I want to compare all dates to current date time  and find the closest date time. Is there any simple way to compare them instead of looping and comparing?

I have tried below example

Date1.after(date2)

date1.compareTo(date2)>0

But I not able to accomplish the result.

I have to compare entire date and time not only date or time

by using below format i have to compare

Date currentTimeDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: Have you done any code for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3884728/1318946

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186311/best-way-to-find-date-nearest-to-target-in-a-list-of-dates?rq=1

Comment: i can't reply anymore so i write here:
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long actualDateMs = cal.getTimeMillis();
    long distance = Math.abs(actualDateMs - ListOfDate[0].GetTime());
    //GetTime() or whichever methods give you milliseconds from date
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < ListOfDate.length; i++){
        long distancePartial = Math.abs(actualDateMs - ListOfDate[i].GetTime());
        if(distancePart < distance){
            distance = distancePart;
            index = i;
        }
    }
at the end the `index` value is the index of the closest date in the list

Answer (score 2):

- Make the list of your Date Objects in a sorted way.
- Then create a Date object for current Date time.
- Now use the logic of Binary search to find the closest Date Time in
  your list.
- Use Joda Time for comparison.

Consider the above points as hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, It will may be helpful to you.

```
public static Date closerDate(Date originalDate, Collection<Date> unsortedDates) {
    List<Date> dateList = new LinkedList<Date>(unsortedDates);
    Collections.sort(dateList);
    Iterator<Date> iterator = dateList.iterator();
    Date previousDate = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Date nextDate = iterator.next();
        if (nextDate.before(originalDate)) {
            previousDate = nextDate;
            continue;
        } else if (nextDate.after(originalDate)) {
            if (previousDate == null || isCloserToNextDate(originalDate, previousDate, nextDate)) {
                return nextDate;
            }
        } else {
            return nextDate;
        }
    }
    return previousDate;
}

private static boolean isCloserToNextDate(Date originalDate, Date previousDate, Date nextDate) {
    if(previousDate.after(nextDate))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("previousDate > nextDate");
    return ((nextDate.getTime() - previousDate.getTime()) / 2 + previousDate.getTime() <= originalDate.getTime());
}
```